# Passing Local Struct to another function by reference

Tags: c

I'm currently working on an assignment for a C programming class. So far everything has gone well except that I'm having trouble passing a local struct variable to a different function. **Per the assignment, I cannot make the struct global.**

Here's what I've got in my main function for creating the struct:

```
struct data
{
    float lat;
    float lon;
    float depth;
    float mag;
};

struct data quake[FileLength];
```

where FileLength is defined previously within the main function.

the fields within "quake" are populated afterwards in the main function.

And here's what I have for the function that I need to pass the struct to:

```
void OverallMinMax(struct* data quake, float* MinLat,float* MaxLat,float* MinLon,float* MaxLon, int* FileLength)
{
int i;
for (i = 0; i < FileLength; i++)
{
    if (quake[i].lat < MinLat)
    {
        MinLat = quake[i].lat;
    }
    if (quake[i].lat > MaxLat)
    {
        MaxLat = quake[i].lat;
    }
    if (quake[i].lon < MinLon)
    {
        MinLon = quake[i].lon;
    }
    if (quake[i].lon > MaxLat)
    {
        MaxLat = quake[i].lon;
    }

}
```

}

The goal of this function is to find the minimum and maximum values for longitude and latitude data that is taken from a file. However, no matter how I try to pass "struct data quake", it doesn't work. Most of the methods that I've tried lead to the compiler  recognizing "quake" but not the data within it, for example `quake.lat` will throw an error saying that `lat` is not recognized. The way I have it in the code above doesn't throw these errors, but instead gives `expected '{' before '*' token` as an error in the line where the function is defined, referring to the "*" that comes after "struct".

Can anyone offer insight as to how I should be doing this?

Answer (score 1):

```
struct* data quake
```

This is wrong. You want:

```
struct data *quake
```

`struct * data` is not a type in C.

Then you also have other other issues:

```
if (quake[i].lat < MinLat)
```

`MinLat` is declared as a pointer so you have to use `*MinLat`. But if you don't have a good reason to pass a pointer in your function, just declare `MinLat` as a `float` and not as a `float *`.

Comment: I'm using the pointers in an attempt to return multiple variables from the function, is there a better way of doing this? I'm just trying something that I found elsewhere on SO

Comment: Why not pass a pointer to a second structure object in your function? Usually when a function takes too many arguments (like yours), it's a sign of bad design.

Comment: So, instead of passing the pointers to the struct and all of those float values, gather the floats into their own struct, and pass a pointer to that?

Comment: @GreatSpaceWhale for example, yes.

Comment: Okay, I did that, and the function declaration looks better, but now the Min and Max values are giving the same errors as the quake ones, where it claims all of the fields used after the "." can not be resolved.